# Software Recommendation SE getting little attention from experienced SO users

Tags: discussion, software-recs-se

In my experience, it seems that very few seasoned/experienced developers, who are frequently seen here on SO, visit http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com, or answer questions there.

I'm specifically bringing this up w.r.t. software-development-related tools and libraries - asking for which is, of course, off-topic here on SO. The question load is rather low - a language tag might get 5-15 questions a month (C++ and Python respectively, last month), and there's much less of the low-quality newbie questions we drown in around here. And yet - a large fraction of the questions have 0 answers and comments; while I'm pretty sure that many high-rep/experienced users here on the site would be able to provide answers had they seen those questions.

So, I ask:

- Do you agree with my description of the state of affairs, or is your experience/information different?
- What, if anything, would you suggest be done to get more experienced SO eyeballs on software recommendation questions?

Comment: I think the better alternative would be to shut it down.

Comment: This assumes that a lot of experienced users even want to engage with those types of questions. They were made off-topic here because they attracted a lot of garbage and were very difficult to maintain. There's a lot of "I just don't want to" sentiment out there.

Comment: I'm not "high-rep" but I have no interest in doing other people's research for them...

Comment: @HereticMonkey no one is asking to do other people's research, you're free to share what you know if you want to, just like you answer homework dumps here on SO ...

Comment: Solving interesting programming problems on a piece of software I'm familiar with presents a fun challenge and sometimes a learning opportunity for me. Recommending software to people? Not so much. Participating on Software Recs just doesn't seem interesting to me, and I don't think anything but changing the subject of the site could help with that.

Comment: @rene From my reading of the help center, and the answers to their meta question  [What is required for an answer to be high quality?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356), there's a lot more to it than "sharing what I know".

Comment: @animuson: Well, I don't know about the past, but from what I can tell, there's not "a lot of garbage" there now, while SO is swamped with "garbage".

Comment: @einpoklum That it isn't there now is only a side-effect of it being a lesser-known site and people would rather try their luck at Stack Overflow. Doesn't mean the idea would effectively work if it got a huge influx in askers. But as I said, most experienced users have already gotten a lot of headache from these questions in the past and have no interest in giving it another try.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: SR.SE is not about doing research for others, it's about sharing what you already know. The amount of effort to give a basic decent answer a question there is much lower than on SO. Of course, you often just don't know a relevant piece of software and then nobody expects you to go looking.

Comment: @animuson: To be more concrete - have you looked at a sample of questions, say, on software related to HTML editing, CSS editing/previewing, browser-like apps etc. , on SR.SX recently? Or - are you generalizing from past experience on SO?

Comment: I just checked the SR.se front page. I think it suffers from the same issue all SEs do: the front page is full of boring, quotidian questions. This is as true of my “home” site, EL&U, as it is of SR.se, as it is of SO. So it’s not a unique situation. However, for those who try dipping their toes into SR.se, as I just did, it might be discouraging. Maybe you can create a Meta.SR thread to collect some of the most interesting Qs? And promote that somehow, eg a link here in your MSO question? Maybe just Qs focused on programming libraries?

Comment: Regarding the low influx of questions I see such questions being closed on SO without noticeable migration.

Answer (score 19):

I can only answer why I'm not participating in Software-Recs:

- It's boring: Solving programming problems on SO is like building a Puzzle. You try to find out what the problem is, test a bit around, and then finally find a solution. Non of this applies to Software-Recs. You just read a spec, you recommend something, no challenge in it. And you don't learn anything yourself. I mostly answer SO question because the topic interest me and I can learn a lot myself by seeing what others are answering and what askers are writing.
- Very limited options to build a long-lasting library of good questions. Almost no specs are that similar that they can be answered by an existing question. Answering questions where it is very likely that no one else will ever need them is not that funny for me. Tools and especially libraries change too frequently. An answer that was perfect a year ago might not be usable after the next version (or after a better library has been released).
- Especially in areas with multiple experts, voting on answers is (in my very limited experience) more a popularity contest of the library/tool than based on the quality of the answers.
- I really don't like the mixed focus on programming tools/libraries and consumer software.

I'm not saying that this are reasons everyone agrees with, but they are the reason for me not to visit this site.

In total, I'm not so sure if this site really serves a good purpose in the SE network. Imho, shutting it down sounds like a better alternative than trying to move more experts from SO to this site. After all, expert time is limit and we already need more experts on SO than we currently have.

Comment: 1. Questions on most SE sites are not like solving puzzles, and are not "interesting" in that way. 2. I'd guess over 90% of questions on SO are not like that either. 3. A long-lasting library of good questions and answers can and is being built; the requests are not usually for super-niche software (which likely hasn't been written by anyone). 4. The voting is not important on SR.SX unless there are multiple questions which offer different pieces of software. 5. Anyway, this has all been decided when that site went out of beta. But having said that...

Comment: Your last point is interesting. I've wondered about that myself.

Comment: It's one thing to say that one is not interested in some other stack exchange site and another to say it should be shut down. That might be a different question.

Comment: @Trilarion I included the last part because op asks how to move resources from SO to SR (expert time is limited). I have no problem with the existence of the site, but I don't like to actively encouraging SO user to spend time there. I guess I should have written that more clearly.

Comment: @Trilarion: Maybe you can check my edit to see if my points is now better covered.

Comment: In my comment above, item (4.), s/multiple questions/multiple answers. Also, @BDL, I think you may not actually aware of what kind of questions get asked there. And - tools and libraries don't change that frequently; and when they do change - new answers are given, or the old tool's homepage suggests trying something else.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I thought that I could add a bit to the discussion, so I posted my own answer. But I think you formulated it very well and balanced now.

Comment: @Trilarion: The more answers, the better :)

Answer (score 3):

> Do you agree with my description of the state of affairs, or is your experience/information different?

Yes, my observation was that software recommendation has a very low amount of traffic. Many questions remain unanswered, which in turn makes asking questions also less profitable and in the end the critical mass to keep Q&A going there might just not be reached. Of course it is far from me to question the existence of any stack exchange.

My impression is also that recommending programming software is not so easy, you actually need to have a certain amount of knowledge to know how well a software library fits a certain purpose, to give a useful specific recommendation. In the end, people tend to try different frameworks/libraries/tools anyway and judge how well they fit their purposes and that's what they should do anyway.

Maybe giving specific recommendations does not scale so well. There is certainly a demand for general listings of programming related software (see for example http://cssframeworks.org/, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators, https://github.com/akullpp/awesome-java, https://alternativeto.net/software/visual-studio/ and many more) but they would not be a good fit for Q&A (it was tried in the beginning, but didn't work).

> What, if anything, would you suggest be done to get more experienced SO eyeballs on software recommendation questions?

If there are actually people interested in answering programming software recommendations which are specific enough to be answerable in Q&A and if the only problem of the software recommendations stack exchange is low amount of traffic, then it might make sense to integrate programming software recommendations in StackOverflow. It would increase the amount of traffic, remove some entry barriers, but might also increase demand for curation, closing those questions where people do not state their requirements.

It's not unheard of, Mathematics for example allows book recommendations if they state their specific requirements. However, the whole thing would need the agreement of both, the software recommendation and the StackOverflow communities. That may not be very likely.

(The non-programming software recommendations of software recommendations might also find a new home at SuperUsers, if we are at it.)

Otherwise I don't see much that can be done. Sure, a bit of advertisement on StackOverflow Meta might have a little impact by making people more aware of the possibility, but that's it.

That might change in the future, if the company decides to integrate technical exchanges more. That might include the programming software recommendations part. They, including the CEO, talked about it in the past months. It would not be clear, if the community will embrace it though, if it ever comes.